# Change Icon Index of shortcut during installation

Tags: installation, windows-installer, installshield

I'm working with InstallShield 2013 Professional, Basic MSI Project.

My installation package contains exe file - **myfile.exe**. I added shortcut for it in Shortcuts view specifying **myfile.exe** as Icon File, and 0 as Icon Index. The destination place for this shortcut is a Desktop on a target box.

Suppose, my executable contains 3 icon resources and I want to change icon dynamically during Installation. To be more clear what I want to do: I have 3 radio buttons on one of Installation Dialogs and I want to apply icon to myfile.exe shortcut depending on radio button that was checked (1-st radio button->1-st icon, 2-nd radio button->2-nd icon, 3-rd radio button->3-rd icon).

How can I get this behavior? In other words, how can I change icon index of Icon File during installation?

Answer (score 1):

This is kind of a complicated request.  An easier way of achieving this would be to compile the EXE three times with different names and different icon 0 resources and then use mutually exclusive component conditions to control which one gets installed.

It gets trickier if that's not an option. The [Shortcut Table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa371847%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) defines the IconIndex column as an integer and is not formattable.  This means you can't say [ICONINDEX] in the field and let it resolve at install time.

So what can you do?  You can use a custom action to dynamically emit table data into temp tables during the install.   An example using C# can be found here at: [Dynamic Windows Installer UI](http://blog.iswix.com/2008/07/dynamic-windows-installer-ui.html)

Realize that if someone creates a shortcut by hand they are likely to pick the "wrong" icon.